# meteor iron router prepends "undefined" to id

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Hi I'm following the Discover Meteor book, and I'm in Chapter 5-3. I have the router.js and post_item.html precisely as the book, and for every url, I get something like `/posts/undefined<id>`.  I can't figure out why undefined is present in front of every id. Below is my relevant code:

```js
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('posts'); }
});

Router.route('/', {name: 'postsList'});

Router.route('/posts/:_id', {
  name: 'postPage',
  data: function() { return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
});
```

```html
<template name="postItem">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-content">
      <h3><a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a><span>{{domain}}</span></h3>
    </div>
    <a href="{{pathFor 'postPage'}}" class="discuss btn btn-default">Discuss</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue caused in the 1.0.8 release as you can check [here](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1357). Update the package to the 1.0.9 release typing in the console `meteor update` or manually `meteor add iron:router@1.0.9` and it should work.